# How the compiler does data binding during compile time?

Tags: c++, data-structures

Compiler binding is replacing the variable names with their addresses.
Amount of memory to b allocated is decided at the compile time.. but it is allocated at run time which means that addresses of variables and functions are not known until run-time..
If memory location is not known...then how is compiler able to convert names into addresses during compile time??

Please guide me if i am wrong somewhere

Comment: Variables with automatic storage duration are allocated on the stack (if not optimized out to registers). Their addresses are derived relatively from stack registers. Just learn how stacks work. (Technically, C++ programs can run on a stackless machine, but nowadays, all mainstream processor architecture use stack.) Consider [this demo](https://godbolt.org/z/M6mTTf), where `i` is on the stack and its address is `DWORD PTR [rbp-4]`, where `rbp` is a stack base register.

Answer (score 1):

Memory allocation is known in terms of offsets from the stack base. When you allocate a variable on the stack, you assign to this variable an offset from the stack base pointer. You also don' care about the exact value of this pointer - you only know that `a` is located at address `[base pointer + 8]`, and this lets you refer to `a` within this function, unless you modify the base pointer yourself.

So the stack may look like this:

```
| Address |  Variable  |
|---------|------------|
| BP + 0  | a(4 bytes) |
| BP + 4  |   b (8 b)  |
| BP+4+8  |     c      |
```

Note that the offsets may be negative or positive, depending on [where the top of the stack is](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/02/04/where-the-top-of-the-stack-is-on-x86/).

---

Here's an example [from Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/RpBDP8):

```
int main(void) {
    char a = 22;
    int b = 23;
    return a + b;
}
```

On ARM, the compiler will store `22` and `23` into `a` and `b` like this, relative to the *stack pointer* (that points to the *top* of the stack, as opposed to the base pointer):

```
movw    r0, #22
strb    r0, [sp, #7]  ; `a` is at SP + 7
movw    r0, #23
str     r0, [sp]      ; `b` is at SP + 0
```

On x86 the offsets will be negative and relative to `rbp` - the base pointer:

```
mov     byte ptr [rbp - 5], 22    ; a (1 byte)  is at BP - 5
mov     dword ptr [rbp - 12], 23  ; b (4 bytes) is at BP - 12
```